# Using Scanf() for taking input for both string and integer

Tags: arrays, c, string, scanf, format-specifiers

I was writing a simple C program to take inputs from user for different variables using `scanf()` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this is coming completely fine, as expected:

```
input: 10 23
output: 10
        23
```

But then I also tried to take input for a string array, as follows(here `char c[2]` is a string array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b;
    char c[2];
    scanf("%d %d %s", &a, &b, c);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%s\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

And now the output was something unexpected:

```
input: 10 23 AM
output: 10
        0
        AM
```

Here, as it can be seen that the value being printed for variable `b` is coming to be `0`, instead of the expected `23`. How did taking input for a string array change the value of variable `b`?

Can someone help figure out, what wrong(of course silly mistake) have I done?*emphasized text*

Comment: `char [2]` is too small to contain 2 letters + 1 null terminator, see linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `char c[2];` variable is not a large enough array to hold a 2-character string **plus the required `nul`-terminator**. If you *know* that the input will be no more than 2 characters, changing to `char c[3];` should be sufficient; however, for added safety, you can include a limit on how many characters will be read by the `scanf` call, using a format specifier like `%2s` (or, more generally, for an array such as `char buff[n];` use a value of `n - 1` in that format specifier).

As it stands, you have ***undefined behaviour*** – and this *may* include overwriting the value given for `b` (with the zero that should be the `nul`-terminator).